# strange behavior of django Q objects

Tags: python, django-models

I have 2 models:

```
class Call(models.Model):
    date_time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 300, blank= True, null=True)
    bought_record = models.ForeignKey('BoughtRecords')

class BoughtRecords(models.Model):
    date_time_bought = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
    bought_packet = models.ForeignKey('BoughtPackets')
```

I wrote 2 queries:

1. `Q1 = Q(call__result = 1)`
   `company_for_call = BoughtRecords.objects.exclude(Q1)`
2. `company_for_call = BoughtRecords.objects.exclude(call__result = 1)`

   I expected the same behaviour from this queries. They generate slightly different sql-queries( I am not good at raw sql=) ).

I suppose thats why Call not always exists for BoughtRecord or may be Q-objects not properly work with backward foreign keys. Explain me please this behaviours, because I often compile complex queries from Q-objects and sometimes get unexpected  result. I want to know about situations in which at first sight result must be simular, but in reality diffent.

Comment: Can you specify the `slightly different` output you get by pasting it in your question?

Comment: In reallity this models have more fields, so sql a few rubished...sorry... here they are: 1) SELECT `target_boughtrecords`.`id`, `target_boughtrecords`.`date_time_bought`, `target_boughtrecords`.`source_record_id`, `target_boughtrecords`.`bought_packet_id` FROM `target_boughtrecords` INNER JOIN `target_call` ON (`target_boughtrecords`.`id` = `target_call`.`bought_record_id`) WHERE NOT (`target_call`.`result` = 1 )

Comment: 2) SELECT `target_boughtrecords`.`id`, `target_boughtrecords`.`date_time_bought`, `target_boughtrecords`.`source_record_id`, `target_boughtrecords`.`bought_packet_id` FROM `target_boughtrecords` WHERE NOT (`target_boughtrecords`.`id` IN (SELECT U1.`bought_record_id` FROM `target_call` U1 WHERE (U1.`result` = 1  AND U1.`bought_record_id` IS NOT NULL)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that in case of using `Q` there is an `INNER_JOIN` with a `WHERE NOT` while calling the `exclude` directly results in the query being a `nested select`. Semantically they are equivalent. When the `INNER JOIN` happens the `NULL` references on the `foreign_key` are excluded. In the case of nested query `target_call.bought_record_id = NULL` is explicitly specified. So there should not be any difference in the results.